# How to do residual & regression deletion diagnostics on spautolm/sarlm objects?

Tags: r, linear-regression, diagnostics, r-sp

In stats there are nice functions to carry out residual & regression
deletion diagnostics on `lm` or `glm` objects, such as:

`stats::plot.lm` and `stats::influence.measures`

*Example:*

```
 lm.object <- lm(sr ~ pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
 plot(lm.object)
 influence.measures(lm.object)
```

I would like to do these (or similar) diagnostics on a `spdep::spautolm`
(type "SAR") object, but neither `plot.lm` nor `influence.measures` accepts
`spdep::spautolm/sarlm` objects.

**Can you recommend a workaround?**

**Or are these diagnostics simply not appropriate for SAR type regressions?**

Answer (score 2):

Objects from `spautolm` have `fitted` and `residuals` methods to retrieve the fitted values and residuals. Some of the outputs from the `lm` methods can not directly used for SAR models because these are computed under different assumptions (not independent errors or observations).

Comment: OK, but how would I do a calculation of, say the leverages, by hand then retrieving the values from a `spdep::spautolm` object? See my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148529/calculating-leverage-cooks-distance-for-a-weighted-spatial-simultaneous-autoreg)

Comment: Depends on whether you want to look at the conditional or the marginal residuals, see e.g. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9868.00119/abstract

Comment: Mh, good question. For checking the model assumptions I guess I would need the marginal residuals...I reckon the `spautolmOBJECT$fit$residuals` are the marginal residuals?!? Given Haslet's paper, I am not sure what the conditional residuals would be in a `spautolm` object. Response - SignalTrend? Leverages would need to be calculated on the basis of marginal residuals, right?